# Android - Foursquare venues search error: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, httprequest, foursquare, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to use **Foursquare's search venue** in my Android application. My URL must be correct, it works OK in a browser, but in my Android app I get an IOException: **java.io.FileNotFoundException**. 
I guess something is wrong with my HTTP request, but i can'r figure out what. Can you please help me with that?

```
new Thread() {
@Override 
public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();   

    try 
    {
        URL url = new URL(  FSQR_URL + 
                            "venues/search?ll=" + Float.toString(latitude) + "," + Float.toString(longitude) + 
                            "&client_id=" + FSQR_CLIENT_ID + 
                            "&client_secret=" + FSQR_CLIENT_SECRET + 
                            "&v=" + timeMilisToString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        String responseBody     = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        try 
        {
            JSONObject response1 = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            JSONObject response2 = new JSONObject(response1.getString("response"));
            setSearch(new JSONArray(response2.getString("venues")));
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            mResult.onError(e.toString());
        } 
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        mResult.onError(e.toString());   
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        mResult.onError(e.toString());
    }   
}
```

}.start();

Comment: Does `FSQR_URL` start with `http:`?

Comment: And do you see the request in the server log; does it find the resource or issue a 404 result code?

Comment: I don't see the server log. I try to log the response of the request, but It throws an exception sooner.

The exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=xxx,xx8&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&v=20130204

Comment: Have you validated that your code passes `setDoOutput()` (btw, you need not do that I'd say) and fails upon `connect()`? Have you logged the resulting URL as a string and validated it? WHat are the details of the Exception you get (use `e.getMessage()` instead of `e.toString()`)?

Comment: ...and remove the cast to `HttpURLConnection` in front of `url.openCOnnection()`; it's superfluent and maybe even counterproductive.

Comment: So did you make any progress?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue. However the request works for me unless I change the near parameter to something unexpected, for example, instead of Chicago,IL I used Chicago,ILLLLLLLLLL and then my application crashes in the same manner as yours in the line where I get the InputStream.

If I paste the same url used by my app into a browser I get this:


{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"failed_geocode","errorDetail":"Couldn't geocode param near: chicago,illlllllllllllllllll"},"response":{}}.


If you have made any progress on this, please let us know.

Thanks!